# Unable to use filters and dimensions in API implementation

Tags: php, api, google-api

I have a following question my `api` connects and can get and call some metrics, but unfortunately, I can not implement filters and dimensions. I need a clearer example as I am unable to find one in the documentation

Thank you very much for your attention. (I'm sorry for the bad English, but it's not my native language)

This is how what it looks like in the IDE

[image: Here is Image]

Comment: Please don't add your code as an image, edit your question and add it as text. Thank you.

Comment: @THess, Sorry, but I'm new to stackoverflow and it said that i need 10 Reputations to post an image

Comment: Even if you have enough reputation you should paste your code as text so it's possible to copy/paste the code to edit/test the code.

Comment: @uclarabellei Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited the formatting and added the images inline the question text. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try to passthe fields as part of the last argument to the get() method.

```
$analytics->data_ga->get('ga:' . $profileId, '7DaysAgo', 'today', 'ga:pageviews', [
    'filters' => $filters,
    'dimensions' => $dimensions
]);
```